# Как считать текст из textbox в массив?

Tags: c++, .net

Суть задания в том что нужно с файла считать текст в текстбокс примерно такой:

```
slovo1
slovo2
slovo3
```

И потом в этом тексте найти то слово которое мы напишем в другом текст боксе. Я считал текст из файла но с поиском вышла проблема. Я решил что лучше будет с текст бокса считать весь текст в массив и потом уже работать с массивом(string). Но из-за того что в дотнете есть функция String^ то это проблематично.
Я пытался сделать так, но ничего не получилсь, как быть?

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (textBox3->Text != nullptr && textBox1->Text != nullptr)
    {
        String^ str = textBox3->Text;
        String^ s = textBox1->Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < s->Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == str)

        }

    }
}
```

Где: textbox1 - тот бокс в котором список слов
textbox3 -  бокс в котором слово которое надо найти

Comment: "Как считать текст из textbox в массив?"
array<String^>^ s = textBox1->Lines;

Comment: @JaponDemon спасибо.